# Could iTextSharp be used to generate PDFs containing the fields in between flowing text

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, itext

Could iTextSharp be used to generate PDFs containing the fields in between flowing text e.g.

```
Thankyou for choosing "ProductNameField". We would ...
```

I would like to fill the "ProductNameField" from DB using iTextSharp. However the length of the field is not fixed so using form fields leaves the spaces around if the field value is smaller in length or causes overflow if the field value is longer than the space given. I looked in to "floating text field" generated by Adobe LiveCycle but could not find a way to use them from iText.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two basic ways to create PDFs with dynamic text:

1. PDF form fields
2. Write the PDF manually

The former allows people to fill out PDFs with Adobe Acrobat/Reader but has the limitation that you saw of fixed length fields.

The second option is what iTextSharp is about. You tell iTextSharp to write a paragraph and it does it for you. If you take some static text and combine it with the database or user entered data doesn't really matter, iTextSharp just wants text.

So yes, iTextSharp can do this.

Are you working with an existing PDF or are you creating a PDF from scratch?

Comment: I am working on creating a solution to let users pick the template and the system fills it with the DB data. I would like the other set of users to be able to create the PDFs just like they do Word mail merge documents. Writing PDF manually is not an option because we don't want the program to change for document changes (e.g. verbiage, formatting). Most of the text in the documents is static so it is best to leave it to regular users to edit and format the documents as they want.

Comment: After trying out various things, I found that if the forms are saved in (Dynamic) XML Form in LiveCycle, the "Floating Fields" within the "Static Text" work as I want i.e. the text around them flows nicely. However, I am having trouble getting my head around acroFields.SetField method vs stamper.AcroFields.Xfa.FillXfaForm method. Also, how to get the XML data to be merged. Another issue I see in this method is that the floating fields are not visible as "fillable" fields but that is fine as I won't need these forms to be filled manually. Those would be templates only.